# Is there a way to reduce complexity when modelling interactions between nodes in a simulation engine?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, time-complexity, simulation

I am building a simulation in Java w/JavaFX UI.

The idea is that I can create many Person objects (in an array) which will contain (x,y) co-ordinates to denote positioning for rendering on the screen. At each step in time I will iterate through the array and apply some to the Person objects to calculate their next position (based on current velocity etc). So far so good...

However, I also want to model interactions between Person objects (make sure that they can't overlap for instance and would just bounce off each other). The only way that I can see to do this is by iterating over the array for each Person to compare their x,y values against every other person e.g.

```
Person [] population = initialisePopulationArray(); //Helper function to just set initial values

//A step in time occurs just before I render the new positions on screen
void step(){

   //Do basic initial calculation on positions O(n)
   for(Person person: population){
      updatePosition(person); //Based on trajectory etc
   }

   //Determine if new positions mean that people are overlapping and resolve O(n ^ 2)
   for(int i=0; i<population.length; i++){ //For every person
      Person person = population[i];

      for(int x=i+1; i<population.length-(i+1); i++){ //Compare against every other person
         compareAndResolve(person, population[x]; // Some function to compare and resolve any issues
      }

   }
}
```

As you can see this gives exponential complexity - is this just the way it has to be in a simulation like this or is there a better way that I have missed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `As you can see this gives exponential complexity` Why is it exponential?

Comment: There is something you missed, yes. Your solution would never work for a couple of million of different objects potentially interacting with each other. Basically you have to split your world into sub areas and keep track of which subarea any object is in and then only compare the objects within each sub area. There is A LOT of stuff to read through to get this working very well, there is probably still active research going on. See e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314828291_Minimal_hierarchical_collision_detection

Comment: @amit Would O(n^2) be considered quadratic rather than exponential? Or some other terminology?

Comment: @luk2302 Okay many thanks! I had a feeling that I was going to get told something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two people don't interact as long as they are farther apart than some distance *d*, then you can divide your world into squares of size *d x d*.  Then you only have check each person against other people in the same or adjacent squares.

In Java you could use, for example, a `Hashmap<java.awt.Point, List<Person>>` to keep track of which people are in each square.

Comment: Okay cheers I will look into doing this once I have my basic version working!